# Groups of equal length with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the df:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c(rep("G1",18), rep("G2", 10)), X = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 8), rep("c", 4), rep("d", 6)), Y = c(rep(1:10), rep(1:8), rep(1:4), rep(1:6)))
```

Possibly by making use of `dplyr` or `tidyr`, I would like to make all subgroups within each `group` the same length, which should be the smallest one among those of the elements of the group. 
Simply put, the resulting dataframe should be:

```
df_r <- data.frame(group = c(rep("G1",16), rep("G2", 8)), X = c(rep("a", 8), rep("b", 8), rep("c", 4), rep("d", 4)), Y = c(rep(1:8), rep(1:8), rep(1:4), rep(1:4)))
```

I cannot focus how I would achieve that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be what you want?

```
library(dplyr)
df_r <- df %>% group_by(group, X) %>% mutate(maxY = max(Y)) %>% 
               group_by(group) %>% filter(Y <= min(maxY)) %>% select(group, X, Y)

> df_r
   group X Y
1     G1 a 1
2     G1 a 2
3     G1 a 3
4     G1 a 4
5     G1 a 5
6     G1 a 6
7     G1 a 7
8     G1 a 8
9     G1 b 1
10    G1 b 2
11    G1 b 3
12    G1 b 4
13    G1 b 5
14    G1 b 6
15    G1 b 7
16    G1 b 8
17    G2 c 1
18    G2 c 2
19    G2 c 3
20    G2 c 4
21    G2 d 1
22    G2 d 2
23    G2 d 3
24    G2 d 4

> df_r1 <- data.frame(group = c(rep("G1",16), rep("G2", 8)), X = c(rep("a", 8), rep("b", 8), rep("c", 4), rep("d", 4)), Y = c(rep(1:8), rep(1:8), rep(1:4), rep(1:4)))
> identical(df_r, df_r1)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I doubt that in real life `Y` is just acceding sequence. I think the idea here was to focus on group size.

Comment: It is possible, however, if it is just about group size, some extra logic is needed to illustrate which rows should be discarded?

Comment: If OP's `Y` is meant to be actual data then creating `subgroup_id = 1:n()` in the first `mutate()` and referencing `subgroup_id` instead of `Y` will keep this answer working just as well.

Comment: The solution was indeed a little tricker than expected, due to what @DavidArenburg and @Gregor have mentioned. That is: the first `mutate()` turns into `mutate(subgroup_id = n())` . After the second `group_by()` a `mutate( to_be_selected = min(subgroup_id))` had to be included, Then, I had to  include the first `group_by()` again and eventually modify the `filter()` into `filter(row_number(time) <= to_be_selected)`.
Then, `select(-c(subgroup_id, to_be_selected))` would get rid of the additional, auxiliary columns.

Comment: Combined these comments to a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, {
        i1 <- tabulate(factor(X))
        i2 <- sequence(pmin(i1, min(i1)))
        .SD[Y %in% i2] } , by = .(group)]
#    group X Y
# 1:    G1 a 1
# 2:    G1 a 2
# 3:    G1 a 3
# 4:    G1 a 4
# 5:    G1 a 5
# 6:    G1 a 6
# 7:    G1 a 7
# 8:    G1 a 8
# 9:    G1 b 1
#10:    G1 b 2
#11:    G1 b 3
#12:    G1 b 4
#13:    G1 b 5
#14:    G1 b 6
#15:    G1 b 7
#16:    G1 b 8
#17:    G2 c 1
#18:    G2 c 2
#19:    G2 c 3
#20:    G2 c 4
#21:    G2 d 1
#22:    G2 d 2
#23:    G2 d 3
#24:    G2 d 4
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, size := .N, by = .(group, X)][
          , size := min(size), by = group][
          , head(.SD, size[1]), by = .(group, X)]
#    group X Y size
# 1:    G1 a 1    8
# 2:    G1 a 2    8
# 3:    G1 a 3    8
# 4:    G1 a 4    8
# 5:    G1 a 5    8
# 6:    G1 a 6    8
# 7:    G1 a 7    8
# 8:    G1 a 8    8
# 9:    G1 b 1    8
#10:    G1 b 2    8
#11:    G1 b 3    8
#12:    G1 b 4    8
#13:    G1 b 5    8
#14:    G1 b 6    8
#15:    G1 b 7    8
#16:    G1 b 8    8
#17:    G2 c 1    4
#18:    G2 c 2    4
#19:    G2 c 3    4
#20:    G2 c 4    4
#21:    G2 d 1    4
#22:    G2 d 2    4
#23:    G2 d 3    4
#24:    G2 d 4    4
#    group X Y size
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly ugly base R answer:

```
# get minimum numbers by group
minCntGroup <- aggregate(Y~group, data=aggregate(Y~group+X, data=df, FUN=length), FUN=min)

# sample indices of df from each group returned as a list,
# using minCntGroup to sample correct size
set.seed(1234)
mySampleVector <- unlist(sapply(unique(levels(df$X)), function(i) 
                         sample(which(df$X == i),
                         size=minCntGroup[minCntGroup$group %in% df[df$X==i,"group"], "Y"])))
```

The `sapply` returns a list that contains indices of the sampled rows for each of the X subgroups keeping the sizes identical within the larger groups variable. I wrap this list in `unlist` to return a vector.

If you want to turn this into a data.frame, you can use

```
df_r <- df[mySampleVector,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments on one of the answers, this is a solution when the variables are not consecutive and which will generalize to other data:

```
out <- df %>% 
  group_by(group, X) %>% 
  mutate(subgroup_size = n()) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(min_subgroup_size = min(subgroup_size)) %>% 
  group_by(group, X) %>% 
  filter(row_number() <= min_subgroup_size) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-c(subgroup_size, min_subgroup_size)) %>%
  ungroup()

table(out$group, out$X)
     a b c d
  G1 8 8 0 0
  G2 0 0 4 4
```

This solution uses 3 grouping steps to get the requested result:

1. First group by (group and X) to determine subgroup sizes
2. Next group one level up on group to get the minimum subgroup size considering all subgroups within one group
3. Lastly, group by (group and X) again and use the minimum subgroup sizes determined before to filter the appropriate number of rows per subgroup.

Optionally replace `filter(row_number() <= min_subgroup_size)` with `sample_n(min_group_size)` to get random row selection within the subgroups.